# Seekbar + media player

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Проигрыватель с seekbar-ом

Тут проблема в layout-e, если seekbar использовать в activity_main то он работает как и должен, т.е при нажатии в определенную точку он переходит туда, но если seekbar установить в content_main и передать его в activity_main через include, не работает, т.е при нажатии в определенную точку он не переходит туда 
проект создан для образца, тут делаем плейер с seekbar-om

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seekBar;
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}


private void initViews() {
    buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1_1);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            seekChange(v);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
private void seekChange(View v){
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
    }
}

public void playAndStop(View v){
    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
        try{
            mediaPlayer.start();
            startPlayProgressUpdater();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

}

выше все работает, проблема в layout-e

1 вариант работает -
activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/play_str"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="playAndStop"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPlayStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

второй вариант нет -
activity_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

---

content_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/play_str"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="playAndStop"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPlayStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Что можно сделать чтобы заработал второй вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Укажите максимальное значение seekBar. 
Пример XML:

```
android:max="//Ваше значение (число)//"
```

Пример java:

```
seekBar.setMax(//Ваше значение (число)//);
```

Comment: seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()); вроде указано, или нужно указывать число?

Comment: Нужно указать число.